# match elements from a list and a dataframe and create a new dataframe under condition if it matches with the list

Tags: r

Hello guys I have a list a dataframe as you see below

```
listA <- list("Jon", "Maria", "Jon", "Maria", "Ben")
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Tina", "Jon", "Jon")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 22, 44)
df <- data.frame(Name, Age)
```

So what i am trying to achieve is to create an if function that will print

```
  if (listA[1] == df$Name)
    print(new_df) #under the condition
##for example a new df with all the Jons and their ages
```

The error I get for something like this is the following because there are more Jons than 1

```
Error in if (...) print(...) : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

I understand how this works for numerical values but I am struggling with the strings. My desired output would be for example a new dataframe that will print the following values for example

```
#if "Jon" is in the list print  new dataframe
Name <- c("Jon", "Jon", "Jon")
Age <- c(23, 22, 44)
new_df <- data.frame(Name2, Age2)
```

If you understand my question could you please provide me with your help?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow, but `lapply(listA, \(x) df[df$Name == x,] )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thelatemail suggested

```
lapply(listA, \(x) df[df$Name == x,] )
```

Zheyuan Li suggested

```
subdf <- df[df$Name %in% unlist(listA), ]
split(subdf, subdf$Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df[which(listA[1] == df$Name), ]
```

- output

```
  Name Age
1  Jon  23
4  Jon  22
5  Jon  44
```